# Spring-Webapps: shared resources and separated development/maven modules?

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-applications, resources

I have two WARs, each one using Hibernate-Search+Lucene. As far as I understand it, that setup would produce two separate Hibernate und Lucene instances if loaded separately into tomcat etc.

The two WARs are generated by two separate maven modules. I want to keep that separation.

How do I merge the separate instances in production?

I thought about the maven-shade-plugin to merge the WARs. Is there a better of doing that, ie. a more automatic/more standard way?

Comment: Are you using your wars seperately?

Comment: Same app server, at the moment Jetty 8.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Maven WAR Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). What is the reason for defining two separate WAR files? 
General idea is to have Base WAR (shared resources?) and two customized WARs (diffs) for diffrent environment with Maven Overlays.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally tried shade, overlay and cargo uberwar strategies for merging two wars. my personal favourite for this requirement is Cargo uberwar. It not only allows basic overlay functionalities but also enhances by additional features which you may like to use. Control over merging strategies of files from different wars is one such example. You may like to merge at least web.xml. You can refer to more examples at http://cargo.codehaus.org/Merging+WAR+files

It may seem additional work setting it up but the configuration options are worth it.